# CodenameOne Designer is not opening up

Tags: codenameone

The theme.res file is no longer opening up on Netbeans. This issue applies for all CodenameOne projects. I have also tried to open the Designer jar. Please see image attached and the issue. Please assist.

[image: CodenameOne Designer Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a regression in the latest update that was resolved just now: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3077

Comment: Thanks Shai, issue is resolved. I updated "Project libs" via CodenameOne Settings.